# Error while creating a custom producer in scala

Tags: kafka-producer-api

I have written a small code for custom producer in Kafka using scala and it is giving the below error. I have attached the code in code section. I have attached some code for reference.

```
Name: Compile Error
Message: <console>:61: error: not found: type KafkaProducer
               val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)
                                  ^
```

I think I need to import a relevant package. I tried importing the packages but could not get the correct one.

```
val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)

for( i <- 1 to 10) {
//producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, String]("jin", "test", 
"test"));
val record = new ProducerRecord("jin", "key", "the end ")
producer.send(record)
```

Comment: Indeed, you need to import a library. Have you tried `import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer` ?

Comment: Yeah already tried importing that library but still same issue...Please let me know in case if you want to see the complete code with libraries which i have used...

Comment: Are you in an `sbt` project ?

Comment: I am currently using jupyter notebook and while compiling the code , it is giving the error. I thought once the code is working, I will add the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I can't install a scala kernel for jupyter right now, but based on [this github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/hdinsight-spark-scala-kafka/blob/master/Stream-Tweets-To-Kafka.ipynb) you should add Kafka as a dependency, then the library might be recognized

```
%%configure -f
{
    "conf": {
        "spark.jars.packages": "org.apache.spark:spark-streaming_2.11:2.1.0,org.apache.bahir:spark-streaming-twitter_2.11:2.1.0,org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.10:2.1.0,com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4",
        "spark.jars.excludes": "org.scala-lang:scala-reflect,org.apache.spark:spark-tags_2.11"
    }
}
```

If this doesn't work, try downloading the whole notebook from the git, and fire it yourself, to see if something else is needed

Answer (score 0):

@Arthur , Magic command %%configure -f did not work in jupyter notebook. I tried downloading the Whole notebook from the git but that also does not work. Luckily I was
reading the apache toree documentation for adding the dependencies and found a command %%addDeps. After putting dependencies in the below format into jupyter notebook,
I managed to run the code.

%AddDeps org.apache.kafka kafka-clients 1.0.0

%AddDeps org.apache.spark spark-core_2.11 2.3.0

Just for the information of others, when we compile the code using SBT, we need to comment this code from jupyter notebook as we will add these in build.sbt file.

Thanks Arthur for showing the direction !